# Elasticsearch is returning all the records when query text is of alphanumeric pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, elastic-stack, analyzer

I have an index in Elasticsearch with mapping as:

```
/price_validity_idx

{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "validity":{
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the data stored in this index looks something like this:

```
{
 "title" : "16 USD product"
"validity": true
}
{
 "title" : "USD 5 refill"
"validity": true
}
.....
{
 "title" : "10 USD"
"validity": false
},
{
"title" : "Movies on Demand-Free of cost"
"validity": false
},
{
"title" : "One month subscription on Cash purchase"
"validity": true
}
```

So, whenever I make **Match Query** on field **title** with query text as alphanumeric (eg.USD 5)
all the records which are having numeric values in the **title** are getting returned as a part of the result.

> For example, curl **-XGET** '/price_validity_idx' -d '{"query":{"match": { **"title": "USD 5"** } }}'

**Output:** (*Removing elasticsearch meta-information for compactness*)

```
{
 "title" : "16 USD product"
"validity": true
},
{
 "title" : "USD 5 refill"
"validity": true
},
{
 "title" : "10 USD"
"validity": false
}
```

But whenever I make the same **Match Query** on the field **title** with only the number as a query text(eg.5), then the particular records which matches the number are returned.

How do I make it return only the records that matches the exact numeric value when query text is of alphanumeric(eg. USD 5). Due to some business restriction I won't be able to change the mapping type to **INTEGER**. Also, I won't be able to use TERM Queries as the field contains a bit lengthy textual data as well.

Please help as I'm new to Elasticsearch.

Version that is used is Elasticsearch-7.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The standard analyzer is the default analyzer which is used if none is specified**. The tokens generated are `usd` and `5`, so all the documents that match any of these tokens will match the search query.

**Analyze API**

```
GET/ _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "USD 5"
}
```

The following tokens are generated:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "usd",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "5",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

> You can use the [match_phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) that analyzes the text and
> creates a phrase query out of the analyzed text.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": "USD 5"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64528215",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.1446278,
        "_source": {
          "title": "USD 5 refill",
          "validity": true
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Edit 1:**

> You can even use [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) with operator `AND`, that is a
> boolean logic used to interpret the text in the query value

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "USD 5",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shivam Som did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: Thanks @Bhavya match_phrase seems to solve the issue.